# Angular 7 how to return data based on value (id) on the view.html

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, ionic-framework

I have a method that returns different data based on ID! What I'm confused about is how to loop through that method on the view!

## The method on the data.service: ( the backend returns data based on ID input )

```
  getProductsByCategoryId(id: number): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._http.get<any[]>( environment.apiURL + `/wc/v3/products/?category=${id}`,  this.autherization)
  }
```

## The method on the home.component.ts:

```
getProductsByCategoriesId(id: number) {
    this._data.getProductsByCategoryId(id).subscribe(
      products => {
        console.log(products);
        this.products = products
      }
    )
  }
```

## The method that I get the Id's from:

```
getCategories(): void {
    this._data.getCategories().subscribe(
      categories => this.categories = categories
    )
  }
```

## The view home.component.html:

Now I loop through categories and I got the `id` on the view! my question is how to loop through products by that **id** using this method `getProductsByCategoriesId` I tried to loop with the method and the page has crashed :"D

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <ion-title> {{ category.name }} </ion-title> <br>

      <ion-slides [options]="sliderConfigration">
        <ion-slide *ngFor=" let p of WHAT?"> // the problem
          <pre>
            test test
          </pre>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your problem you should get all the data before it goes to view. For example, `this.categories` each single category should have its products e.g.

```
this.categories[0].products = [{...},{...}]
```

To achieve this first you need to change in the following function

```
getProductsByCategoriesId(id: number) {
this._data.getProductsByCategoryId(id).subscribe(
  products => {
    console.log(products);
    //this.products = products; // commented this line
    this.categories.forEach(category => {
      if (category.id == id)
       category.products = products;
    });
  }
 )
}
```

After this in the view part make these changes to show the products from the category `category.products`

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <ion-title> {{ category.name }} </ion-title> <br>

  <ion-slides [options]="sliderConfigration">
    <ion-slide *ngFor=" let p of category?.products"> // the problem
      <pre>
        test test
      </pre>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to your approach it works! but not the code you have written because of the  `getProductsByCategoriesId()` not getting fired so there's no way to check the ids! 

So I have to configure and edit the 2 methods the categories one and the products one either!